# while reading json data from url using python gives error "urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden"

Tags: python, json, urllib, urllib2, urllib3

with this code I am reading a URL and using the data for filtration but urllib could not work

```
url = "myurl"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())
```

yesterday it was working well but now giving me error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vaccine_survey.py", line 22, in <module>
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 532, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 642, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 570, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Comment: Did you research what 403 forbidden means? what steps did you take in attempt to fix this? (hint: authenticate, use an API key etc)

Comment: The error is pretty clear: the server is blocking you for some reason. Maybe it needs authentication information, maybe you're on a block list.

Comment: but it was working well in browser , i can see data in in text format

Comment: Might be checking user agent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this works for me, here 'myurl' is a url address

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

req = Request('myurl', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
response = urlopen(req).read()
data = json.loads(response.read())
```